# Choosing Between SQL Logic and Frontend Mapping for Dynamic Data Presentation

Tags: sql, mysql, reactjs, node.js

I have a MySQL database table named "Tablets," which includes a column called "compartment" (compartment INT NOT NULL UNIQUE). The compartment value can only range from 1 to 32.

I'm tasked with implementing a screen where I need to list all 32 compartments as follows:

```
compartments         tablets
compartment 1   :       dollo
compartment 2   :       unoccupied
compartment 3   :       paracetamol
.
.
compartment 32  :       unoccupied
```

For each of the 32 compartments, I need to display either the tablet name if it exists for that compartment, or "unoccupied" otherwise.

As I have to create an API for this functionality, I'm considering two options:

1] Logic in SQL:
In this approach, the API would return all compartments with available schedules, or "unoccupied" if there are no schedules for a compartment.

2] Logic in Application Code:
With this approach, the API would return only tablet schedules. The mapping of compartment numbers to schedules would be handled in the frontend, displaying "not occupied" text if there are no schedules for a compartment.

Could you please help me decide which approach is more suitable and recommended for this scenario and in general???

1st approch- Logic in SQL, Api will be something like this :

```
module.exports.getAllCompartmentsWithSchedules = async (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.userId;
  try {
    // Query to retrieve all compartments along with their schedules for the logged-in user
    const query = `
      SELECT compartments.compartmentNo, 
             IFNULL(schedules.occupied, FALSE) AS occupied, 
             IFNULL(schedules.schedules, '[]') AS schedules
      FROM (
        SELECT compartmentNo
        FROM (
          SELECT 1 AS compartmentNo UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
          UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8
          UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12
          UNION SELECT 13 UNION SELECT 14 UNION SELECT 15 UNION SELECT 16
          UNION SELECT 17 UNION SELECT 18 UNION SELECT 19 UNION SELECT 20
          UNION SELECT 21 UNION SELECT 22 UNION SELECT 23 UNION SELECT 24
          UNION SELECT 25 UNION SELECT 26 UNION SELECT 27 UNION SELECT 28
          UNION SELECT 29 UNION SELECT 30 UNION SELECT 31 UNION SELECT 32
        ) AS compartments
        LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT compartment, TRUE AS occupied, JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(
            'medicineName', medicineName,
            'quantity', quantity,
            'day', JSON_PARSE(day),
            'time', time,
            'dose', dose,
            'start_date', start_date,
            'end_date', end_date
          )) AS schedules
          FROM Tablets
          WHERE userId = ?
          GROUP BY compartment
        ) AS schedules ON compartments.compartmentNo = schedules.compartment
      ) AS compartments
      ORDER BY compartments.compartmentNo;
    `;

    const [rows] = await pool.execute(query, [userId]);

    return res.status(200).json(rows);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error while fetching compartments with schedules:", error);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
};
```

---

2nd approach- logic in frontend will be like this:

```
const response = await axios.get('/api/getAllCompartmentsWithSchedules');
    const rows = response.data; 
    const compartments = {};
    rows.forEach((schedule) => {
      const compartment = schedule.compartment;
      if (!compartments[compartment]) {
        compartments[compartment] = [];
      }
      compartments[compartment].push({
        medicineName: schedule.medicineName,
        quantity: schedule.quantity,
        day: JSON.parse(schedule.day),
        time: schedule.time,
        dose: schedule.dose,
        start_date: schedule.start_date,
        end_date: schedule.end_date,
      });
    });

    const response = Object.keys(compartments).map((compartment) => ({
      compartmentNo: parseInt(compartment, 10),
      occupied: true,
      schedules: compartments[compartment],
    }));

    for (let i = 1; i <= 32; i++) {
      if (!response.find((compartment) => compartment.compartmentNo === i)) {
        response.push({
          compartmentNo: i,
          occupied: false,
          schedules: [],
        });
      }
    }

    response.sort((a, b) => a.compartmentNo - b.compartmentNo);
```

---

and The api will be simply fethcing the schedules of user:

```
  const userId = req.userId;

  try {
    // Retrieve all compartments along with their schedules for the logged-in user
    const [rows] = await pool.execute("SELECT * FROM `Tablets` WHERE `userId` = ?", [userId]);

    return res.status(200).json(rows);
  }catch(error){}
};
```

Comment: Without having really looked much at your code: All you want to know from the database is the tablets, so `select * from tablets` and you are done with that part. That there can be 32 compartments, and that you want to show all 32, and that you want to display missing tablets with the English word 'unoccupied', and that you want to use JSON for some reason are all things that I see outside the DBMS. Put these in your API code.

Comment: Shouldn't you have a separate `compartment` table rather than giant `UNION`? At the very least you can change that to a `VALUES`?

Comment: And `GROUP BY compartment` doesn't seem to make sense on a table wherein compartment is unique. Or must it be a JSON array although it is guaranteed to contain only one JSON object?

Comment: we can just ignore the code currently.
as you said correctly, I have tablets in db, each with any compartment(out of 32).
My goal is to map each compartment to a schedule, and if no corresponding schedule is found, it should be mapped to 'Unoccupied'.
I'm unsure whether I should implement this logic while fetching records from the database itself or if I should simply fetch the tablet records and implement this logic to generate the desired variable containing compartments with mapped values on the frontend.
@Thorsten Kettner & thank you for your help

Comment: You are talking about 32 compartments. Does the DBMS know that it is 32 compartements? Is there a compartement table with 32 rows? Then yes, get your data via joins from SQL. Else just get the tablets data and care about those 32 outside of SQL. The JSON part does not belong on the SQL side, as you are not storing anything in JSON here. Just select the data and format it outside of SQL. Same goes for the word 'Unoccupied'. In SQL the absence of a value is NULL, so select NULL. Don't make 'Unoccupied' a fixed value in a query. At some point you may want another word (another language maybe).

Comment: Yes I have table Compartments wich has 32 compartments. 

 I have added the final query Which I used, in next comment.

its working perfectly fine. Thank you for you help. It indeed was very Insightfull. @Thorsten Kettner

Comment: SELECT 
    c.compartmentNo, 
    IFNULL(
        (
            SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
                'isOccupied', true,
                'medicineName', t.medicineName, 
                'time', t.time, 
                'dose', t.dose, 
                'start_date', t.start_date,
                'end_date', t.end_date
            ) 
            FROM Tablets t 
            WHERE t.compartment = c.compartmentNo
            LIMIT 1
        ), 
        JSON_OBJECT('isOccupied', false)
    ) AS details
FROM Compartments c
ORDER BY c.compartmentNo